# PHP Regex ignoring nested tags

Tags: php, regex

Hi I'm working on a bug in a CMS and I was hoping someone could give me some help with this messy regex! I need to remove everything inside the {{page?  }} tags (where 'page' is a dynamic word), including any nested {{tags}} within them.- except for {{links? }}

In the code below, the regex should remove everything inside the {{homepage? }} tag:

```
<div id="main">   
    <div id="left">
    {{menu1}}<br />

{{homepage?
    <img src="images/{{timenow}}.gif" width="177" height="217" alt="{{imgname}}" id="biglogo" />
}}

{{links?
    <b>LINKS</b>
}}
</div>
{{menu2}}
</div>
```

Here's what I have so far. It's getting stuck as soon as it sees the `timenow}}`

```
$result=preg_replace("#\{\{(?!links)\S*?\?.*?}}#s","",$result);
```

**Clarification:**

There are no `{{page? }}` sub tags (all subtags are `{{thisformat}}` ). 
In other words something like: `{{foo? {{links? bar }} baz }}` would never occur.

Comment: What `{{page? }}` tags? You mean `{{homepage? ... }}`? Do you actually want to remove all tags except the links tag? What what happen with `{{foo? {{links? bar }} baz }}`? Or do you just want to grab the content of links tag(s)?

Comment: That might be simple enough with a recursive regex using the `(?R)` syntax. In your case you might get away with: `"#\{\{(?!links)\w+\?((?R)|.)*}}#s"` - but the `.` should be rewritten to something more specific.

Comment: Sorry @Qtax by `{{page? }}` I meant the word page is dynamic (can be any single word like homepage, links, contact, etc). There are no {{page? }} sub tags (all subtags are {{thisformat}} ) so your example would never occur.  

@mario - looks promising. I'll give it a blast and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:
`#\{\{ (?!links\b) \w+ \? (?: \{\{\w+}} | [^{}]+ | \{(?!\{) | }(?!}) )* }}#sx`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, there's no need for recursive matching here; the `{{page? }}` tags may contain simple tags like `{{this}}`, and that's it.  In that case, you just have to watch out for the beginning of a nested tag, so you can match the end of that tag when it shows up, then go on looking for either the end of the enclosing `{{page? }}` tag or the beginning of another nested tag.

```
$regex='#
  \{\{ (?!links\?) \w++\?     # page-tag start
  (?:
    (?: (?!\{\{|\}\}) . )++   # normal content
  |
    \{\{                      #
    (?: (?!\}\}) . )*+        # embedded tag
    \}\}                      #
  )*+
  \}\}                        # page-tag end
#sx';
```

The "normal content" part matches one or more of any character, unless the next character is the beginning of a `{{` or `}}` sequence.  Once we've started to match an embedded tag, we use the same technique to gobble up its content.

**[see it in action at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Yhq1z)**

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible with regex. Read about the millions of failed attempts to parse nested html/xml with regex.

Comment: he's not parsing *ML tho, and matching recursive structures is easy, but it's probably better to write a parser. :)

Comment: The problem about parsing XML with regex is the nesting.

Comment: Don't let the title confuse you  - there's actually only one level of nesting in this question, making the language regular.

Comment: Knowing that would have helped :)